# Force sequence of EXPECT_CALLs

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to test two serial port write+read calls. The first one has to block on `read` for 101ms and thus cause a timeout error. The second one should run fine. Based on the [google mock manual](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#ordered-vs-unordered-calls) the `InSequence` variable should ensure that. Here is the code:

```
  {
    // This variable ensures the sequence order
    InSequence s;

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Write(_, _))
        .With(ElementsAreArray(command1_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(Write));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Read(_, _, _))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(TimeoutRead));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Write(_, _))
        .With(ElementsAreArray(command2_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(Write));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Read(_, _, _))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArrayArgument<0>(response_begin, response_end),
                        SetArgumentPointee<2>(response_.size()),
                        Return(true)));
  }
```

`TimeoutRead` is just a function that causes current thread to sleep for 101ms.
However, I keep getting this runtime error:

```
[ RUN      ] MasterTest.LostReply
/host/Users/blah/work/bitbucket/master_test.cc:631: Failure
Mock function called more times than expected - returning default value.
    Function call: Read(0x5652c3f31120 pointing to "\xFF\xFF", 4096, 0x7ffda19d2960)
          Returns: false
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: called twice - over-saturated and active
```

It seems that GTest is trying to call the last `EXPECT_CALL` designed for the second `read`.

Is there a way to enforce this sequence of calls?

---

**[THIS IS TEMPORARY EDIT TO PRESENT SSCCE YOU NEED TO PROVIDE TO GET ANSWER]**
This is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) I expect you update appropriately to get error you are mentioning in your question. The code below works and passes:

```
class Serial_
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(Write, void(int* elems, size_t n));
    MOCK_METHOD3(Read, bool(int* elems, int dummy, size_t* n));
};

int command1_[] = {1,2,3};
int command2_[] = {4,5};
std::array<int, 4> response_{{ 6, 7, 8, 9 }};

void testScenario(Serial_& serial_)
{
    int dummy_arr[100];
    size_t dummy_size;
    serial_.Write(command1_, 3);
    serial_.Read(dummy_arr, 123, &dummy_size);
    serial_.Write(command2_, 2);
    serial_.Read(dummy_arr, 123, &dummy_size);
}

bool TimeoutRead(int* elems, int dummy, size_t* n)
{
    return true;
}

void Write(int* elems, size_t n)
{}


TEST(A,A)
{
    Serial_ serial_;

    // This variable ensures the sequence order
    InSequence s;

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Write(_, _))
        .With(ElementsAreArray(command1_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(Write));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Read(_, _, _))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(TimeoutRead));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Write(_, _))
        .With(ElementsAreArray(command2_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke(Write));

    EXPECT_CALL(serial_, Read(_, _, _))
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArrayArgument<0>(response_.begin(), response_.end()),
                        SetArgumentPointee<2>(response_.size()),
                        Return(true)));

    testScenario(serial_);
}
```

Comment: Check if this `With(ElementsAreArray(command2_))` constraint to second Write happens or not.  Or - just check if second write happens. E.g. remove all ElementsAreArray checks... ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz How will missing second `write` will cause the second `EXPECT_CALL(Read)` to be matched twice? It seems to me that the sequence requirement isn't working.

Comment: This is much too small information. Please present the code you are testing. And the `serial_` mock definition and the best would be http://sscce.org/

Comment: @PiotrNycz Thanks for taking a stab at it. `TimeoutRead` has `std::this_thread::sleep_for(11ms)` in it to cause the wrapper of the `serial_` mock functions to timeout and fail.

Comment: @PiotrNycz I found the bug in my own code, thanks to your hints. Not sure how to award the bounty then.